# Moped::Errors::ConnectionFailure Could not connect to any secondary or primary nodes for replica set

Tags: mongoid, mongoid3

I had to forcefully shutdown my `Ubuntu` system after it got hanged. Now I get this error while trying to run my `Rails` app.

```
Moped::Errors::ConnectionFailure (Could not connect to any secondary or primary nodes for replica set <Moped::Cluster nodes=[<Moped::Node resolved_address="127.0.0.1:27017">]>):
```

Im using `Rails 3.2.11` with `Mongoid 3.1.4`.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was able to get it working by removing the `mongod.lock` file and restarting `mongodb service`

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo service mongodb start
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall mongodb using

```
sudo apt-get autoremove mongodb-*
```

then install with

```
apt-get install mongodb-server
```

run mongo 
it will solve the problem