# Error Could not connect to any secondary or primary nodes for replica set <Moped::Cluster nodes=[<Moped::Node resolved_address="127.0.0.1:27017">]>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to follow rails3-domains at https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-subdomains, but after I git clone, I get the error Error Could not connect to any secondary or primary nodes for replica set ]>

What could be the issue?

Comment: Is your mongodb running?

Comment: how do I check/or run?

Comment: Run `mongod` in the terminal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180106/mopederrorsconnectionfailure-could-not-connect-to-any-secondary-or-primary-n