# Can't run Rails 4 app with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid4

I want to use MongoDB in my rails application and facing a problem:

> Could not connect to a primary node for replica set #]>

This is what I've done to set up my project:

Created a new project with the following command, in order to replace Mongoid with rails active-record:

```
rails new hellomongoid --skip-active-record
```

Added 'mongoid', '~4.0.0' and 'bson_ext' gems to my Gefile and ran bundle install successfully.

Generated the mongoid:config with this command:

```
rails g mongoid:config
```

Generated new scaffold:

```
rails g scaffold Car model:string manufacturer:string year:string
```

Started the MongoDB with the Mongod command, and started the rails application in localhost.

Now I get this annoying error message when I try to reach localhost:3000/cars.
It says that it occurs right here:

```
 <tbody>
   **<% @cars.each do |car| %>**
     <tr>
       <td><%= car.model %></td>
       <td><%= car.manufaturer %></td>
```

Where I was wrong?

Both the Mongod and my rails Mongoid config set to port 27017...

EDIT:

This is my mongoid.yml file:

```
development:  
  sessions:    
    default:      
      database: yomongo_development      
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:        
  options:    
test:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: yomongo_test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        read: primary        
        max_retries: 1
        retry_interval: 0
```

Comment: Can you all add your mongoid.yml

Comment: Is `mongod` running and accepting connections?

Comment: I ran into a similar problem before. This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180106/mopederrorsconnectionfailure-could-not-connect-to-any-secondary-or-primary-n

Comment: @Nerve it keeps telling me --> connections:0

Comment: @Coderhs added it to the question.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. If you encounter this error and working with Windows, you might want to change the:
- localhost:27017 line to -->
- 127.0.0.0:27017
and that will do it.